# Struggles deploying an umbraco built blog

Tags: sql-server, azure, deployment, connection, umbraco

I'm struggling deploying an umbraco built blog through Microsoft Azure.

I have a finished Umbraco database i exported to Microsoft Azure SQL Database.

I have a finished the blog i've deployed to an Azure app service.

I have connected the blog to the Azure SQL Database connectionstring.

But when i publish my website i get redirected to an Umbraco first-time-install. Instead of my Homepage with all the contents. And i know the tables are in the Azure SQL Database through MSSQL.

The blog works perfectly on localhost. I run IIS if that could be something that makes a difference.

Any ideas what i miss?

Answer (score 0):

Is it saying you need to upgrade or install? If it is install then your connection string is either wrong or your database is not an Umbraco database.

Comment: It redirects me to an Umbraco page that tells me i've got no content on the page. That's why i get redirected there.

I can get to the umbraco login page but the logins ain't working. And i've checked the database more than twice and the logins and tables exists.

The content from my site however ain't showing either.

Comment: Just noticed the "or your database is not an Umbraco database", Do you mean by Azure? I uploaded the Umbraco database with tables on a normal SQL-Database service on Azure.

Comment: You can reset your admin password using this:
https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-admin-reset/

However if you still can't log in, then I'm certain that there is a problem connecting to the DB (e.g. firewall, error in connection string or SQL user security).